# Scala, accessing classof abstract type in a trait

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I am experimenting with implicit variables in my Scala code. I wrote the following sample code but unfortunately it fails to compile. I was wondering, does  anybody know what is missing here ? (using scala 2.8.0 with SBT 0.7.4 on linux)

Thanks,
Ali

```
trait Feed 
trait FeedFactory  {   
type T <: Feed   
implicit val op_name = classOf[T].getCanonicalName    
def create():T   
def destroy(op:T)   
}

Error: class type required but FeedFactory.this.T found    
implicit val op_name = classOf[T].getCanonicalName
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

type T is forgotten at compile time (see type erasure). But scala offers `Manifest`s that retain type through compilation.

Here is a more complete [explanation](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/manifests-s.html).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with implicit val op_name = {
    def op_name[T](implicit m : scala.reflect.Manifest[T]) = {m.getClass.getCanonicalName} ;     op_name   } but I feel it looks kinda ugly, as I need to define an implicit variable, is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: @Ali with scala 2.8, you should be able to use `def op_name[T:Manifest] = implicitly[Manifest[T]].getClass.getCanonicalName`

Comment: Ali your solution doesn't work. It always returns Nothing. You should probably write val op_name = { def op_name[T](implicit m : scala.reflect.Manifest[T]) = {m.getClass.getCanonicalName} ; op_name[T] } and it says error: No Manifest available for X.this.T